# Conditional Update of column in DataFrame in python

Tags: python, dataframe, conditional-statements, pyspark

I need to conditionally update a column in dataframe based on values present in one of the columns.

For example, based on values in COL9, I want a NEW column COL10 to have values A/B/C (lets say based on below criteria)

```
0.00-0.50 : A
0.51-0.75 : B
0.75-1.00 : C
```

Expected Output :

```
      col1..col8      col9     col10
0      0.788310     0.211690      A
1      0.293871     0.706129      B
2      0.002207     0.997793      C
3      0.047834     0.952166      C
```

Can this be done in a performance efficient manner ?

Answer (score 4):

You can use `pd.cut()` and label the categories the way you wanted:

```
import pandas as pd
df['col10'] = pd.cut(df['col9'], [0, 0.5, 0.75, 1], labels = list("ABC"))
```

[image]

Comment: thanks...

I used :

df2['col10'] = df2['col9'].map(lambda x: 'C' if x < 0.5 else 'B' if x < 0.75 else 'A')

Answer (score 1):

This is a perfect situation for a User-Defined Function (UDF). If you need more flexibility (create more than one column from you input, for instance), then you can look at [transformers](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.6.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/ml/Transformer.html).

Your UDF would look something like the following:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import udf

def colToString(num):
    if num >= 0 and num < 0.5: return 'A'
    elif num >= 0.5 and num < 0.75: return 'B'
    elif num >= 0.75 and num < 1.0: return 'C'
    else: return 'D'

myUdf = udf(colToString, StringType())
df.withColumn("col10", myUdf('col9'))
```

Here, `myUdf` takes a parameter which is a double and returns a string. The double value is read from the input column, `col9`.

The key is to use dataframe operations to perform this, not Pandas. Pandas will not perform your operations in a distributed manner, while Spark will.

Answer (score 1):

While there is a very good answer for using pandas dataframes, since you mentioned pyspark in the tag I assume you mean spark dataframes?

If so you can do something like this:

```
import pyspark.sql.functions.when,lit

newDF = df.withColumn("col10", when(df["col9"] < 0.5, lit("A")).otherwise(when(df["col9"] > 0.75, lit("C")).otherwise(lit("B"))
```

I assumed legal values for the columns are 0-1 but if you need to explicitly check them you can simply change the conditions and add an additional when/otherwise for illegal values